# Install/upgdate to Qt 5.15 from PPA on 18.04.5 LTS (Bionic)

Tags: apt, ppa, qt5

I'd like to install Qt 5.15 from this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ebeineri/+archive/ubuntu/opt-qt-5.15.2-bionic) (I don't want to use the installer). I've added the PPA but I cannot find an apt get command that installs the **all** the packages in the right order i.e. `sudo apt install "qt515*"` produces the error

```
...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 qt515networkauth-no-lgpl-dbg : Depends: qt515networkauth (= 5.15.2-1basyskom1) but it is not installable
 qt515webglplugin-no-lgpl-dbg : Depends: qt515webglplugin (= 5.15.2-1basyskom1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update` after adding the PPA?

Comment: @ajgringo619 Yes I did

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the discussion here?
[https://launchpad.net/~savoury1/+archive/ubuntu/qt-5-15](https://launchpad.net/%7Esavoury1/+archive/ubuntu/qt-5-15)
There's a lot more to update than just the Qt 5.15 stack.

> Qt 5.15.x - backports (Xenial & newer) PPA description Backport of Qt
> 5.15.x stack (and dependencies) for Xenial, Bionic & Focal.
>
> This PPA also requires compatible KDE 5.80.x backports for any system
> that has KDE-based software installed. So make sure to read the notes
> at the KDE 5.80 PPA for latest info about the KDE backports before
> proceeeding:
>
> [https://launchpad.net/~savoury1/+archive/ubuntu/kde-5-80](https://launchpad.net/%7Esavoury1/+archive/ubuntu/kde-5-80)
>
> Note (21 Aug 2021): If any dependencies are missing after adding the
> PPAs described in the install instructions below then make sure to
> inform me so that the dependencies can be copied here or to the KDE
> PPA as appropriate.
>
> *** Install ***
>
> NOTES FOR ALL: Upgrading the system Qt stack is a major system change
> as a lot of highly used software depends on Qt (ie. digiKam as one
> example) and the KDE stack must also be upgraded to a newer version
> (>= 5.80.0) that is compatible with newer Qt 5.15.x software. So
> remember to do a full backup first, same as before any such major
> upgrade! All these PPAs are required for full functionality and
> installation of the backported Qt/KDE packages:
>
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/qt-5-15   sudo
> add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/kde-5-80   sudo add-apt-repository
> ppa:savoury1/gpg   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/ffmpeg4
>
> Also, the VLC 3 PPA is a requirement for Xenial to install Phonon
> backend for VLC (requires >= 3.0), and recommended for all series. Add
> like this:
>
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/vlc3
>
> Note for Focal: Core Qt 4 packages of qt4-x11 and qtwebkit are built
> here allowing Qt 4 (not KDE 4) applications to run on the current
> latest LTS.
>
> Notes for Xenial & Bionic: All qt*-opensource-src packages here are
> built with GCC 9.3.0 and also against ppa:savoury1/display with latest
> display stack upgrades. These Qt upgrades then require GCC 9.3.0 and
> the latest display stack to install and run, so add these two PPAs
> with the commands:
>
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/gcc-defaults-9   sudo
> add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/display
>
> Notes for Xenial: Some required Qt packages are at
> ppa:savoury1/qt-xenial which has backports of the Qt 4 & 5 stacks from
> Bionic. The matching KDE stack from Bionic is also required for proper
> Qt 4 & KDE 4 support. Also, backported APT/GTK from Bionic is needed
> for some Qt/KDE backports. So add these four commands at the top of
> the above list of commands for install:
>
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/apt-xenial   sudo
> add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/gtk-xenial   sudo add-apt-repository
> ppa:savoury1/qt-xenial   sudo add-apt-repository
> ppa:savoury1/kde-xenial
>
> NOTE FOR ALL: After adding all required PPAs (see above) do these
> steps:
>
> sudo apt-get update   sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get
> dist-upgrade
>
> *** Build ***
>
> This PPA has build dependencies on:
>
> ppa:savoury1/build-tools   ppa:savoury1/backports
> ppa:savoury1/python   ppa:savoury1/fonts   ppa:savoury1/graphics
> ppa:savoury1/multimedia   ppa:savoury1/ffmpeg4   ppa:savoury1/vlc3
> ppa:savoury1/display   ppa:savoury1/llvm-defaults-12
> ppa:savoury1/kde-5-80
>
> Additionally, for Xenial & Bionic:
>
> ppa:savoury1/gcc-defaults-9   ppa:savoury1/node-{xenial,bionic}
>
> Additionally, for Xenial only:
>
> ppa:savoury1/apt-xenial   ppa:savoury1/perl-xenial
> ppa:savoury1/gtk-xenial   ppa:savoury1/qt-xenial
> ppa:savoury1/kde-xenial
>
> *** Credits ***
>
> - Creators of Qt: Haavard Nord, Eirik Chambe-Eng and the entire Qt team   https://wiki.qt.io/About_Qt
> - Package code: Debian Qt/KDE Maintainers   https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/qtbase-opensource-src