# Okular does not respond anymore, needs Qt_5.15

Tags: 20.04, snap, qt5, okular

I have Ubuntu 20.04 running on my system and was using the pdf-viewer Okular until recently. However, now Okular does not start when double clicking on a pdf-file and starting from the terminal gives the following error message:
`` okular: /snap/okular/109/kf5/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by okular) ``
Any ideas how can I fix that?
I was thinking of trying `sudo apt-get install qt5-default` which I found on https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu but this is the command for Ubuntu 12.10 and there it says explicitly that it will produce an error on Ubuntu 16.04. Since I did not want to break my system, I decided to post a question here before trying anything.
I will appreciate any advice on how to get Okular running again.

Comment: This existing question may help. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300439/install-upgdate-to-qt-5-15-from-ppa-on-18-04-5-lts-bionic

Answer (score 7):

Remove Snap version by

```
snap remove okular
```

and install deb-packaged version instead by

```
sudo apt-get install okular
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem. I have no idea why, but it did.

BTW, after the second command I got (among other things):
`okular is already the newest version (4:19.12.3-2ubuntu1)` and 
`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`
The last line was a bit confusing, since it says that nothing was installed but Okular was there again and working properly! (In case someone else with the same problem is confused too and thinks the commands hasn't worked.)

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling the snap (it worked for me)

```
snap remove okular
snap install okular
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu 16.04, apparently snap package is not working anymore and is not even listed anymore on Okular website. Instead the flatpak package works. So solution for me was to remove snap package and install the flatpak one.